# Flyback converter MOSFET driver

Tags: mosfet-driver, flyback, ac-dc

I am building a flyback converter to convert 230V AC to 20V DC using a microcontroller. So far my simple converter works, but I have to power the MOSFET driver such as [HCPL-3101](https://mm.digikey.com/Volume0/opasdata/d220001/medias/docus/895/HCPL-3100,3101.pdf) from a secondary DC source, for example a bench power supply or a battery.

[image]

I would like to eliminate that and use the existing AC source to power it. I attempted to use the rectified DC and step it down using a resistor, diode, Zener and capacitor. It can step down the voltage in open circuit but not enough power to drive the MOSFET. I think I can increase the capacitance and it may work but is there a better solution?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE.  To get a good answer, you need to ask a nice clear question and provide suitable background information.  In this case schematics of the existing circuit that you are looking to enhance would be a good start, along with details of how you have thought about enhancing.  It would also be useful to know target power levels.

Comment: Schematic is needed.

Comment: Welcome! Any particular reason you're not using an off-the-shelf DC/DC controller or regulator which will solve these issues for you as in startup and aux supply?

Comment: @winny I would like to be able to implement my own control scheme using the micro controller.

Comment: @Andyaka schematics added

Comment: Why are there two schematics?

Comment: What do you need to control? How will you implement things like peak current limitation? Is your HP-3101 a HCPL-3101 by any chance?

Comment: @Andyaka first one is with power supply which works, second one is with resistor, diode, zener and capacitor which is not a working and I want to improve it

Comment: @winny yes they are the same. do not worry about control, that is not relevant to my question

Comment: You need to put values on a schematic. You also need to explain how you are achieving galvanic isolation from earth in your first image. Please also provide a link for the data sheet for the hp-3101

Comment: @Andyaka I only want a replacement for the V2 which is a battery. the onlu think that came to my mind is the second schematic which does not work. [hp-3101](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/64629/HP/HCPL-3101.html) is a Power MOSFET/IGBT Gate Drive Optocoupler so it is isolated

Comment: You need an aux winding on the primary side of your transformer in order to get a 12 V supply once the D8-R4-C3 is depleted. You need to make sure the transition between the two works or it will keep restarting. UVLO for it would also be something taken care of if you went with a dedicated IC DC/DC regulator or controller but now you need to create that yourself.

Comment: What MOSFET and what maximum switching frequency are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two halfway-decent options here:

- The usual way to do this is to add an extra winding on the primary side of the transformer, called an auxiliary or aux winding. You can use your existing diode-resistor-zener setup to power the chip for the first few cycles, and then use the aux winding as a second output of the flyback to provide power to the chip. The aux winding doesn't need to provide much power, so it can be wound with pretty small wire. Most off-the-shelf flyback controllers are designed to be powered this way.
- The less usual way, but one that would work, is to use a capacitive dropper ("transformerless power supply") off the incoming AC to power the chip. I don't recommend this, personally, but if something prevents you from using a different transformer, this would be the best option I can think of. Since you're on the primary side anyway, the lack of isolation isn't an issue.

Comment: A downside to the capacitive dropper is the DC link voltage rises significantly at very light load (comparable to the dropper's current flow).  That is, the FWB circuit begins looking like a full-wave doubler, when some impedance connects from GND to the AC side. Perhaps both (a "bleeder" from DC link, plus capacitive dropper) would be an acceptable compromise?